# Iterate over individual bytes then save it into a file without alternating the content

Tags: python, laspy

I have a byte string returned from API and store in `response.content`

With small content, I can save it into a file with no problem using the following code

```
with open(save_path, 'wb') as save_file:
    save_file.write(response.content)
```

But for the larger file, it will cause Memory Error, So I tried not to read the content all at once, by using this code

```
with open(save_path, 'wb') as save_file:
    for x in response.content: 
        save_file.write(bytes(x)) #the x from iteration seem to be converted to int so I convert it back
```

But the method above seems to alternate the content because it doesn't compatible with another library anymore (In my when **Laspy** try to read the saved file, `laspy.util.LaspyException: Invalid format: h0.0` error appears)

How can I do it?

Comment: Try changing `'wb'` to `'ab'` and see what happens. It looks like every time you write the next part, you are erasing the rest of it, and should be in `'a'` (append) mode instead of `'w'` (write) mode.

Comment: You might open file results to see what happened in 2 ways for easier checking

Comment: Thanks, Fricative Melon and Tấn Nguyên for suggestions. I tried changing it to 'ab' as you said. But the problem still occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see your problem on using `bytes(x)`. change it to `x.to_bytes(1, 'big')` solve your problem

Use below code to reveal what difference

```
a = b'\xcf\x84o\xcf\x81\xce\xbdo\xcf\x82'
a.decode('utf-8') # τoρνoς

with open('./save.txt', 'wb') as save_file:
    for i in a:
        print(i.to_bytes(1, 'big')) # write it to file, not the others
        print(i)
        print(bytes(i))
        print('----')
```

[image]